# Jackson @XmlRootElement missing for XML occasionally

Tags: xml, jackson

I'm using Jackson v2.5.3 to serialize a Java Bean to XML. The class looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ROOT")
public class classA{
    @XmlElement
    String aString;
    @XmlElement
    String bString;
}
```

The issue that I am encountering is that I receive the XML output of occasionally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<classA>
    <aString></aString>
    <bString></bString>
</classA>
```

What we expect should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <aString></aString>
    <bString></bString>
</ROOT>
```

It seems that root node name is wrong. Class name was used rather than the definition of @XmlRootElement.

Answer (score 1):

To enable support for JAXB annotations in Jackson, you need to include this dependency for Jackson 2.5.3:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Register JaxbAnnotationModule module in your XmlMapper.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Jackson 2.5.3 produces this XML:

```
<ROOT xmlns="">
    <aString/>
    <bString/>
</ROOT>
```

Jackson 2.9.0 produces this XML:

```
<ROOT>
    <aString/>
    <bString/>
</ROOT>
```

To take this further to render exactly like you posted, you need to customize the serialization.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;

class EmptySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

And register this with your mapper:

```
    XmlSerializerProvider provider = new XmlSerializerProvider(new XmlRootNameLookup());
    provider.setNullValueSerializer(new EmptySerializer());
    xmlMapper.setSerializerProvider(provider);
```

This produces your desired format.

```
<ROOT>
    <aString></aString>
    <bString></bString>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Thanks for you kindly help.My question is that most of time the searialization from bean to xml is correct but occasionally the root tag name is wrong with class name rather than the the definition of @XmlRootElement. The errror occured when JVM ran for a while and after restart JVM the issue disappeared.